# Atmel ATMega8 doesn't hold "HIGH" state of PB0 and PB1

Tags: avr, c, atmega

I'm new in microcontrollers and I wrote simple program that set HIGH state at PB0 and PB1.

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>

#define F_CPU 8000000L

int main(void){
    DDRB |= (1<<PB0) | (1<<PB1);
    PORTB |= (1<<PB1);
    PORTB |= (1<<PB0);

    while(1){}
}
```

The problem is that my avr can't hold on HIGH state and connected leds are blinking. Where is the problem ?

Comment: What does your circuit look like? How do you know the MCU isn't just constantly resetting? How are the LEDs connected, and are you sure they aren't blinking LEDs?

Comment: Can you describe how the LEDs blink? Do you have a scope and can you probe the power and LED pins? Oh, and please add a schematic.

Answer (score 1):

Which ATmega exactly? What is your fuse configuration?

You can try calling `wdt_disable()` at the beginning (it is defined in `<avr/wdt.h>`), as the watchdog can be enabled for example by previous firmware (watchdog is not disabled after a reset) or can be by always enabled at reset.

There is also a fuse setting that does not allow disabling of the watchdog - you have to call `wdt_reset()` somewhere in the main loop.

Comment: This is Atmega8. I didn't set any fuse bits.

Comment: which atmega8 specifically? come on, try to be as verbose as possible if asked for details; make sure the fuses are what you expect them to be.

Comment: @MarcusMüller [ATMega8](http://www.atmel.com/images/atmel-2486-8-bit-avr-microcontroller-atmega8_l_datasheet.pdf) is a specific Atmel part.

Comment: @TomCarpenter my understanding was that fuses were specific to case variant, but it seems I was mistaken. My apologies, Mattsky!